# Saving a two dimensional array (matrix) outside the life cycle of the application

Tags: android

For storing two-dimensional integer data (**matrix**) during the life of an application, it takes only one line of code (int myArray[][] = new int[][]) to store this data within the activity, and a relatively simple procedure (like for any other type of variable) using "intent" for transfer between activities.

However, if you want to store exactly the same data **outside** the runtime of the application, all the solutions that have been offered (for which I'm grateful) involve dozens of code lines.

Does anyone have a simple solution (I mean, as simple a the transfer between activities, or as simple as saving a string variable to SavedPreferences) for saving matrices outside application runtime?

Comment: Just write a function to save an array to a file, and read it from a file.  Done.  It should take less than a dozen lines of co de in each direction.

Comment: Would you have any code for that?

Answer (score 0):

You basically just need to convert the 2D array into a string and then store it in a file. Something along the following lines should work as you require.

```
private fun writeFileOnInternalStorage(context: Context, sFileName: String, sBody: Array<IntArray>) {
    val file = File(context.getFilesDir(), "mydir")
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdir()
    }
    try {
        val gpxfile = File(file, sFileName)
        val writer = FileWriter(gpxfile)
        writer.append(sBody.map {
            //Convert the array to string using separators
            it.joinToString(separator = ",")
        }.joinToString(separator = "|"))
        writer.flush()
        writer.close()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}

private fun readFileOnInternalStorage(context: Context, sFileName: String): Array<IntArray> {
    var result = emptyArray<IntArray>()
    val file = File(context.getFilesDir(), "mydir")
    if (!file.exists()) {
        return result
    }
    try {
        val gpxfile = File(file, sFileName)
        val reader = FileReader(gpxfile)
        val content = reader.readText()
        //Convert the string back into a 2D array using the separators
        result = content.split("|").map {
            it.split(",").map {
                Integer.parseInt(it)
            }.toIntArray()
        }.toTypedArray()
        reader.close()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return result
}
```